# How to find confidence interval for Uniform([a,1])?

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics

> Let $ U_1, \dots, U_n $ be a random sample of uniform distribution
>   over $ [a,1] $. Construct a confidence interval for $ a $ with $ 1-\alpha = 0.95 $.

I managed to show that $ T = \min\{U_i\} $ is a sufficient statistic with
$$
  \mathbb{P}(T \le t) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(T > t) = 1 - \left( \frac{t-a}{1-a} \right)^n.
$$

Now I would like to estimate confidence interval for $ T$ since it's a good estimator of $ a $:
\begin{align*}
  & 1-\alpha = 1 - \mathbb{P}(T > t) \\
  & \alpha = \mathbb{P}(T > t) = \mathbb{P}(1 > T > t) = \left( \frac{t-a}{1-a} \right)^n \\
  & t = ((\alpha + a)(1-a))^{-n}
\end{align*}

The problem is, $t$ depends on unknown parameter $a$. What am I doing wrong?

*Edit*: Following suggestions in the comments, I analyze statistic $ S = \frac{T-a}{1-a} $. Let $t$ be observed minimum of measurements.

\begin{align*}
  & 1-\alpha = \mathbb{P}(S \leq t) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(S > t) = 1 - t^n \\
  & \alpha = t^n, \quad\alpha^{1/n}=t \\
\end{align*}

Going back from $S$ to $T$:
\begin{align*}
  1-\alpha
  &= \mathbb{P}(S \leq t) \\
  &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{T-a}{1-a} \leq \alpha^{1/n}\right) \\
  &= \mathbb{P}(T \leq (1-a)\alpha^{1/n} + a) \\
  &= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{T-\alpha^{1/n}}{1-\alpha^{1/n}} \leq a \right) \\
  &= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{T-\alpha^{1/n}}{1-\alpha^{1/n}} \leq a \leq 1 \right)
\end{align*}

That would imply the confidence interval (with $1-\alpha = 0.95$) is $\left[\frac{t-\alpha^{1/n}}{1-\alpha^{1/n}}, 1\right] = \left[\frac{t-0.05^{1/n}}{1-0.05^{1/n}}, 1 \right]$. Is this reasoning correct? I'm worried that left side of the interval can quickly go below zero and it does not say anything useful about this distribution.

*This problem belongs to my homework assignment.*

Comment: Wouldn't my interval still depend on $a$ then? If $ \mathbb{P}((T-a)(1-a)>t)=t^{-n}$ and $t=\alpha^n$, then still I have to move all $a$'s to the right side inside $\mathbb{P}$. And the right side is range end.

Comment: $t$ is not unknown: it is the *observed* minimum of the data.  You can therefore solve for $a$ in terms of $t$ and $\alpha.$

Comment: I made a mistake; work with $S=\frac{T-a}{1-a}$ instead.

Comment: Thank you @StubbornAtom, I updated the post.

Comment: Okay the idea is correct, but you need to find $P\left(\frac{T-a}{1-a}\le t\right)$ first as a function of $t$. Then set that equal to $1-\alpha$ and solve for $t$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Comment: Have a good think about the upper bound you are presently giving for your interval.  Is there any lower value that would be a better upper bound (e.g., without derogation of coverage probability)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem stems from calculation of the probability $P(T \le t)$; it should be

\begin{align}
P(T\le t)&=1-P(T>t)
\\&=1-(P(X_1>t))^n
\\&=1-\left(\frac{1-t}{1-a}\right)^n\qquad,\,t\in(a,1)
\end{align}

For every $0<a<1$ and $0<s<1$, this yields $$P_a\left(0 \le \frac{T-a}{1-a}\le s\right)=P_a\left(\frac{T-s}{1-s} \le a \le T \right)=1-(1-s)^n.$$

If you set that last probability to $1-\alpha$ and solve for $s$, you will have your confidence interval.

Comment: Thanks to @Ben for the correction.